# How to implement a thread safe singleton dictionary class for caching?

Tags: c#, dictionary, singleton

I am trying to implement a thread safe dictionary singleton class for caching purpose.

```
namespace SingletomDict
{
public sealed class MySingleton:IDisposable
{
    private static readonly Lazy<MySingleton> coll = new Lazy<MySingleton>(() => new MySingleton());

    private static Dictionary<string, object> mycoll;

    public static MySingleton Instance 
    {
        get
        {
            return coll.Value;
        }
    }

    private MySingleton()
    {
        mycoll = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    private void SetProperty<T>(string name, T value)
    {
        mycoll.Add(name, value);
    }

    private object GetProperty(string name)
    {
        object value = mycoll[name];
        return value;
    }

    public dynamic this[string index]
    {
        get { return GetProperty(index); }
        set { SetProperty(index, value); }
    }
    public void ReSet()
    {
        mycoll = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
}
```

In the main method, I will be invoking the object as

```
  MySingleton.Instance["LS"] = "AAA";

  MySingleton.Instance["AB"] = "BBB";

  MySingleton.Instance.ReSet();
```

I  did some research to find the correct implementation. But I couldn't find the appropriate example. Thanks

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it probably belongs on Code Review

Comment: Why does your class implement IDisposable?  This makes no sense

Comment: @NetMage, I want to implement a thread safe Singleton dictionary class

Comment: @maccettura - thanks, yes it won't make any sense. Is my implementation thread safe?

Comment: The `ConcurrentDictionary` is a thread-safe `Dictionary`

Comment: Or use `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache`

Comment: ok, I will use ConcurrentDictionary instead of Dictionary

Comment: `mycoll.Add(name, value);` should be `mycoll[name] = value;`

Answer (score 3):

First declare an interface that describes how you want to use this. Perhaps `ICache` with a get and set method. (I'd steer clear of `dynamic`.)

```
public interface ICache
{
    T Get<T>(string key);
    void Set(string key, object value);
}
```

Then write an implementation. Your implementation doesn't need to specify what the internals are.

```
public class Cache : ICache
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> _cache 
        = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();
    public T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        object cached;
        if(_cache.TryGetValue(key, out cached) && cached is T)
        {
            return(T) cached;
        }
        return default(T);
    }

    public void Set(string key, object value)
    {
        _cache.AddOrUpdate(key, value, (s, o) => value);
    }
}
```

If you want to make this a singleton, you can make the constructor private and create a static singleton instance. I would lean toward not doing that. It's better for other classes to depend on the `ICache` interface than on the implementation, and an interface doesn't have static methods.

Depending on the interface means that you can substitute it with different implementations, like one that depends on `MemoryCache`.

```
public class InMemoryCache : ICache
{
    private readonly MemoryCache _cache = MemoryCache.Default;

    public T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        var cached = _cache[key];
        return cached is T ? (T) cached : default(T);
    }

    public void Set(string key, object value)
    {
        _cache[key] = value;
    }
}
```

If you use a dependency injection (IoC) container you can tell it which implementation of `ICache` to use for a class that needs an instance of it, and you can specify that the same instance should be provided each time. That way you get to use a single instance of your class as if it was a singleton without having to code it as a singleton.